# Applying action filter globally giving Redirect Loop exception in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, global-asax, asp.net-mvc-filters

**Problem Statement:**

I'm trying to redirect user to login page if session expires or if user tries to access any view without logging in MVC 4 using razor.

- Instead of applying action filter globally in filter.config if i use
  filter attribute for every action methods it works fine.
- I don't want apply this action filter to each and every action
  method.

I want to apply it globally.How to avoid redirect loop by applying action filter globally?? How to achieve this??

**Login Controller :**

```
//Get Method
public ActionResult Index(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}

//Post Method
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LoginModel loginModel, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        objLoginDC.LoginID = loginModel.LoginID;
        objLoginDC.Password = loginModel.Password;
        if (objSvcMasterConfig.IsValid(objLoginDC))
        {
            var varLoginTenantUserDetails = objSvcMasterConfig.GetLoginUserDetails(objLoginDC);
            Session["User"] = varLoginUserDetails[0];
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(objLoginDC.LoginID, objLoginDC.RememberMe);

            return RedirectToLogin(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The Log In ID or Password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    return View(loginModel);
}
```

**Filters(Action Filter):**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CheckUserSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
        var user = session["User"];

        if (((user == null) && (!session.IsNewSession)) || (session.IsNewSession))
        {
            session.RemoveAll();
            session.Clear();
            session.Abandon();

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Login" }, { "action", "Index" } });
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**Filter Config.cs:**

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new Filters.CheckUserSessionAttribute());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try not executing your filter logic when the controller is **Login** and the action is **Index**:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CheckUserSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //do not execute the filter logic for Login/Index
        if (filterContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller").Equals("LogIn", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            && filterContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action").Equals("Index", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)){
            return;
        }

        HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
        var user = session["User"];

        if (((user == null) && (!session.IsNewSession)) || (session.IsNewSession))
        {
            session.RemoveAll();
            session.Clear();
            session.Abandon();

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Login" }, { "action", "Index" } });
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```